# My function is not running while making web

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, web

I am kinda learning to make typing website and when i trying to random write sth on h2 when i trigger the start button but my function is not responding , even when i do console it doesnt show any response

i was trying to show the text of array words when i trigger the button but my playgame function aint working

`html`

```
<div class="firstDIv">
        <div class="centerDiv">
            <h1>WELCOME TO THE SPEED TYPING TEST</h1>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <h2 id="msg"></h2>
            <textarea name="" id="mywords" cols="110" rows="10" placeholder=" START TYPING" ></textarea>
    
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button id="btn" class="mainbtn" align="center">START</button>
        </div> </div>
```

`JS`

```
  const words = [
      "THIS IS A TYPING WEBSITE",
      "TYPE YOUR WORDS",
      "YOU CAN TYPE WORD"];

    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    const typeWords = document.getElementById('mywords');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    let startTime, endTime;

    playgame = () => {
        let randomtext = Math.floor( Math.random()*words.length)
        msg.innerText = words[randomtext];
    }
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(this.innerText == 'Start'){
            typeWords.disabled = false;
            playgame();
        }
    })
```

note:- CSS is not shown here

Comment: you should also read into how to use chrome dev tools debugger to go through your script line by line to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should be:

```
if(this.innerText == 'START')
```

instead of,

```
if(this.innerText == 'Start')
```